# FluentDOM get raw html of query

Tags: php

I am trying to get a html-part of some html source and tried using FluentDOM for that purpose. When I use the querySelector to select the wanted element I don't see any variables with the raw html code but instead only text. Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible?

```
// $html = my source code
$document = FluentDOM::load(
  $html,
  'text/html',
  [FluentDOM\Loader\Options::ALLOW_FILE => TRUE]
);

foreach ($document->querySelector('div.wrapper') as $el) {
    echo '<pre>' , print_r($el), '</pre>';
}
```

What I get:

```
Lorem Ipsum
list 1
list 2
```

What I want to get:

```
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<ul>
<li>list 1</li>
<li>list 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _“I don't see any variables with the raw html code”_ - you’re working on the DOM level now, so what relevance should “HTML code” have at this point? HTML code was only the input, the “instructions”, that lead to the creation of this DOM structure. If you still need HTML for some reason - then you would have to call the `SaveHtml` method of a particular node, to get a HTML representation of it. https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM/wiki/Element-SaveHtml (Note, that is “a HTML representation”, not “the”.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.